# De-identify(encrypt) data using Pig

Tags: python, scala, apache-pig

I am dealing with Healthcare data in my company. In my current project i need to de-identify(encrypt) some healthcare data using **pig**, **python** or **scala**. I also want to get back the original data like encrypting it. I searched but not able to find any solution. Please help

Comment: did you check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083291/encrypting-data-in-python

Comment: @Sandesh i tried using pycrypto but as it turned out there is a limit of string characters.

Comment: As far as i know , this cannot be done by pig . You may have to explore python in deeper here :)

Comment: Thanks @Sandesh for your help.